GoogleSheets stacking matrix into columns of 3
I have a tabular dataset that needs to be joined into 3 columns. There are 147 columns and 127 rows.

Example dataset



A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O




A1
B1
C1
D1
E1
F1
G1
H1
I1
J1
K1
L1
M1
N1
O1


A2
B2
C2
D2
E2
F2
G2
H2
I2
J2
K2
L2
M2
N2
O2


A3
B3
C3
D3
E3
F3
G3
H3
I3
J3
K3
L3
M3
N3
O3


A4
B4
C4
D4
E4
F4
G4
H4
I4
J4
K4
L4
M4
N4
O4



Expected output



A
B
C




A1
B1
C1


A2
B2
C2


A3
B3
C3


A4
B4
C4


D1
E1
F1


D2
E2
F2


D3
E3
F3


D4
E4
F4


G1
H1
I1


G2
H2
I2


G3
H3
I3


G4
H4
I4


J1
K1
L1


J2
K2
L2


J3
K3
L3


J4
K4
L4


M1
N1
O1


M2
N2
O2


M3
N3
O3


M4
N4
O4




Tip: You can use this markdown table generator to create the markdown_format of the spreadsheet data cells & add it to your question effortlessly


You may try:
=let(data,A1:O4,grp,3,
 reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(columns(data)/grp,1,1,grp),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,choosecols(data,sequence(grp,1,c))))))



Perfect! Thank you!
